# build constraints exclude all Go files go build for amd64 system

Tags: go, terraform

I'm having an issue `go build` binary for `wsl` system inside my windows machine.

Go version:
`go version go1.16.7 windows/amd64`

I set `$env:GOOS="linux"` and `$env:GOARCH="amd64"`

The thing is that I have `C` code inside my project
I have inside `utils` folder `cert_conversion.go` which includes

```
//#cgo CFLAGS: "-IC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include"
//#cgo LDFLAGS: "-LC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib" -llibcrypto
// #include "pfx.h"
```

the error I'm gettings

```
package ravendb
        imports ravendb/ravendb
        imports github.com/ravendb/terraform-provider-ravendb/utils: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Work\terraform-provider-ravendb-1\utils
```

I'm not sure how to make it work.
Any idea ?

Comment: You have to have cgo enabled when the package uses cgo. `CGO_ENABLED=1`

Comment: im getting these errors gcc_linux_amd64.c:61:2: error: unknown type name 'sigset_t'; did you mean '_sigset_t'?
   61 |  sigset_t ign, oset;
      |  ^~~~~~~~
      |  _sigset_t
gcc_linux_amd64.c:66:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'sigfillset' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   66 |  sigfillset(&ign);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
gcc_linux_amd64.c:61:16: error: unused variable 'oset' [-Werror=unused-variable]
   61 |  sigset_t ign, oset;
      |                ^~~~
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors

Comment: Seeing that the given flags are windows specific paths, it may be that this package is only compatible with windows.